# Multiplayer iOS game architecture... Can you merge all connections into a single game scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, multiplayer, multipeer-connectivity

I am using Swift and SpriteKit and (plan to use) MultiPeer Connectivity as my multiplayer platform.

What potential architectures can I use with this platform and SpriteKit? Is it possible for one node to be the "host" node and have other parties join into that game scene?

Or do I need each node to be it's own host and then just send relevant data to all the others?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although the multipeer connectivity framework does not have an idea of a "host", you can certainly write code to have one node function as the host.

You should read the official documentation on how Multipeer Connectivity, it will probably answer any other questions you might have.